# performance comparison on coalesce vs 'is null'

Tags: sql

```
select * from zzz t1
INNER JOIN yyy T2
on (T1.col1 = T2.col1 )
and (T1.col2 = T2.col2 or (T1.col2 is null and T2.col2 is null ) )
```

VS

```
select * from zzz t1
INNER JOIN yyy T2
on (T1.col1 = T2.col1 )
and (coalesce(T1.col2, '\0') = coalesce(T2.col2, '\0'))
```

Or if there's a third, better, way to do this I'd appreciate that too. This is something I find myself constantly doing because half of our databases allow nulls and half of them don't so comparisons suck.

The only thing is I need to avoid things that aren't standard, I use too many different dbs and I'm trying hard to get away from anything that isn't supported by all of them unless the performance gain is utterly magical. (db2, oracle, sqlserver are the main ones I'm using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a database has `NULL` safe comparisons, then the best approach is:

```
select *
from zzz t1 join
     yyy T2
     on (T1.col1 = T2.col1 ) and
        (T1.col2 is not distinct from T2.col2);
```

(This is supported by DB2 but not Oracle or SQL Server.)

Otherwise, I think your two versions are going to be equivalent in most databases at least.  The use of functions/`or` limits the ability to use indexes for `col2`.

Comment: SQL Server supports the operation, but not the syntax: it can convert `EXISTS(SELECT T1.col2 INTERSECT SELECT T2.col2)` to an equality operation internally (as you can see from a query plan). It's standard syntax, I think, but less likely to be optimised well by other database systems.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to clarify.. I was really excited by that syntax but had been scratching my head trying to make it work in Oracle and the error I was getting wasn't very useful.

Comment: Postgres, Firebird and HSQLDB also support `is not distinct from`

Comment: Accepting this answer, a little early but nobody is disputing this and I've been thinking about it for a couple days now anyhow. Was interesting to learn the non-standard syntax as well.